# How to pass variables to a sub-chunk in modx

Tags: php, parameter-passing, modx, modx-revolution, chunks

I have a snippet in ModX that looks something like this:

```
$array = array(
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => 'Title of Story',
    'content' => 'Content of story...'
);

echo $modx->getChunk('chunk_story_page', $array);
```

My story page HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="story">
    <h1>[[+title]]</h1>
    <div class="content">
        [[+content]]
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to be able to call another chunk from within that chunk and pass my data through it. I placed the following below the above HTML.

```
[[$chunk_story_page_extra &title=`[[+title]]`&content=`[[+content]]`]]
```

It goes without saying anything, but the line above is not producing any output.

Any clue on what I might have done wrong on that line? I'm sure it has something to do with the syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a question mark after the chunk name:

```
[[$chunk_story_page_extra? &title=`[[+title]]` &content=`[[+content]]`]]
```

You could also do this, might be slightly more efficient too:

```
$array = array(
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => 'Title of Story',
    'content' => 'Content of story...'
);
$array['chunk_story_page_extra'] = $modx->getChunk('chunk_story_page_extra', $array);

echo $modx->getChunk('chunk_story_page', $array);
```

And in your chunk:

```
[[+chunk_story_page_extra]]

<div class="story">
    <h1>[[+title]]</h1>
    <div class="content">
        [[+content]]
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which one did you go with?

Comment: I went with your first answer. Thanks